# I want to debug an ASP.NET MVC app in IIS using a custom URL defined in HOSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having trouble setting up VS2010 so I can debug in IIS:

- I have added some custom URL's to HOSTS
- I have edited the application properties to use local IIS
- I have created a virtual directory in IIS

Any good resources fro setting this up?

Comment: since you have accepted the answer, you should consider voting his answer up :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy your application to IIS and, when it is running, try to attach to the process from the Visual Studio Debugger (in `Debug / Attach to Process`).
Make sure your web.config have debug mode turned on and the assemblies are compiled with debug symbols.